# UiPickerView with custom fixed label and autolayout

Tags: cocoa, uipickerview

I need to implement a `UIPickerView` to choose hours, minutes and seconds. I need to have a label, next to each component that stay fixed when the picker spin. For example you can look at the timer section of the Apple Clock app. I put an image for reference

[image]

of course I need a picker with 3 components but the problem is the same. I found a lot of solution to add a label as a subview and position it using some frames and manual adjustment but a can' t make it work with AutoLayout and i don' t find a solution on the web. Anyone has solved this problem? thanks

Comment: Any particular reason for the autolayout? It's not really possible by simple means because the internals of the picker view are not exposed, so creating constraints against the internal hierarchy is error prone and not recommended. In this case, I would subclass a `UIPickerView` (like Apple's `UIDatePicker`) and implement all logic there using calculated frame positions.

Comment: I understand your point of view so instead of Autolayout the question become "how to implement a `UIPickerView` subclass that work with every screen size and also in landscape and portrait screen orientation

Comment: For the record, Apple's UIDatePicker does NOT subclass UIPickerView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar problem in an App I worked on and decided on the following:

i.   Create the UIPicker

ii.  Find the midpoint of the presented Picker rows.

iii. Add two UILabels to the screen and in - `(void)layoutSubview;` make sure the labels are always position next to the midpoints.

I only needed portrait mode support in my project, but should work fine for landscape as well. Just choose a wide enough, row width, such that you do not have any overlap with the data inside the picker. Here a snippet of code for the UIPicker:

```
#pragma mark - Picker View

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(component == 0) {
        return self.hourPickerData.count;
    } else {
        return self.minutePickerData.count;
    }
}

- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return 40;
}

- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return 30;
}

-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    NSString *text;

    if(component == 0) {
        text = self.hourPickerData[row];
    } else {
        text = self.minutePickerData[row];
    }

    UILabel *label = (UILabel*)view;
    if(view == nil) {
        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 30)];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.text = text;
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        label.textColor = LYTiT_HEADER_COLOR;
        label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:LT_HELVETICA size:16];
    }

    return label;
}
```

Comment: I don' t understand your proposed solution.

Comment: @Luca - could you please elaborate on which part you do not understand?

Comment: I need a fixed label next to each component of the `UIPickerView and I don't understand how to position the fixed label next to the components in the layout subview method

Comment: From the Apple documentation: layoutSubviews - Implement this method if you need more precise control over the layout of your subviews than either the constraint or autoresizing behaviors provide. This method is called after the auto-layout has occured such that you can use them together. The basic idea is, that you know the height of your picker in advance, hence you know the mid-point of your picker. Since you also know the width of every component (you specifiy this yourself in the delegate method), you know where to position your labels for them to appear exactly on the right spot .

Comment: @AceGreen i didn't write out the method, as it should be clear from the description how to implement it. Let me know if you bump into any problems doing so however. A code sample to point to your exact problem would be helpful :)

Comment: @trdavidson showing the code for layoutSubviews would make your answer more helpful. thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4.2**

[image]

After create pickerView add next code:

```
// Fixed labels
let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.0)
let fontSize: CGFloat = font.pointSize
let componentWidth: CGFloat = self.view.frame.width / CGFloat(agePickerView.numberOfComponents)
let y = (agePickerView.frame.size.height / 2) - (fontSize / 2)

let label1 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: componentWidth * 0.65, y: y, width: componentWidth * 0.4, height: fontSize))
label1.font = font
label1.textAlignment = .left
label1.text = "Years"
label1.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
agePickerView.addSubview(label1)

let label2 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: componentWidth * 1.65, y: y, width: componentWidth * 0.4, height: fontSize))
label2.font = font
label2.textAlignment = .left
label2.text = "Years"
label2.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
agePickerView.addSubview(label2)

let label3 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: componentWidth * 0.05, y: 0, width: componentWidth , height: fontSize))
label3.font = font
label3.textAlignment = .center
label3.text = "From"
label3.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
agePickerView.addSubview(label3)

let label4 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: componentWidth * 0.95, y: 0, width: componentWidth , height: fontSize))
label4.font = font
label4.textAlignment = .center
label4.text = "To"
label4.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
agePickerView.addSubview(label4)
```

Answer (score 2):

I thought others could benefit from my additional answer.

For i components, the following should be in your pickerView initialization method (viewDidLoad),

```
    float fontSize = 20;
    float labelWidth = self.view.frame.size.width / [self.myPickerView numberOfComponents];
    float y = (self.myPickerView.frame.size.height / 2) - (fontSize / 2);
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(labelWidth* i, y, labelWidth, fontSize)];
    label.text = @"Label";
    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontSize];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake (0,1);
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;


    [self.myPickerView insertSubview:label aboveSubview:[self.myPickerView.subviews objectAtIndex:[self.myPickerView.subviews count] - 1]];
```